# SQL query to LINQ expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, orm

How can I translate this SQL query to a LINQ expression?

```
select NoteDate, SUM( DurationInHours ) from Note 
where IDUser = '2933FB9C-CC61-46DA-916D-57B0D5EF4803' and 
      NoteDate > '2013-07-01'
group by NoteDate
```

I tried it, but it didn't work

```
var lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1); 
var userNotes = GetNotesByUser(idUser); 
var b = from note in userNotes 
        group note by new {note.IDUser, note.NoteDate, note.DurationInHours} into g 
        where g.Key.NoteDate > lastMonth  
        select new {g.Key.NoteDate, TotalHours = g.Sum(a => a.DurationInHours)}
```

Comment: This is a great place to learn LINQ queries. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: var lastMonth = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-1);
            var userNotes = GetNotesByUser(idUser);

            var b = from note in userNotes
                    group note by new {note.IDUser, note.NoteDate, note.DurationInHours}
                    into g
                    where g.Key.NoteDate > lastMonth 
                    select new {g.Key.NoteDate, TotalHours = g.Sum(a => a.DurationInHours)}                                                                       

I tried it, but dont work. I saw this examples @CamBruce but i have some urgency. Ill study it with more time! Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var id = new Guid("2933FB9C-CC61-46DA-916D-57B0D5EF4803");
var date = new DateTime(2013, 7, 1);

var query = from n in db.Notes
            where n.IDUser == id && n.NoteDate > date
            group n by n.NoteDate into g
            select new {
                NoteDate = g.Key,
                Sum = g.Sum(x => x.DurationInHours)
            };
```